# Javascript not downloading fully

Tags: http, networking, corrupt

Ok, this might be more of a networking question than programming but I'm not really sure what is going on here:

I'm having intermittent problems with my site where I am only partially downloading javascript documents. By intermittent, I mean that on the same browser (Safari in this case) I can view that javascript file in my browser and refresh the page and still only see the file partially downloaded, but another browser (Chrome) I see the file correctly downloaded. Clearing the browser cache has no effect either.

The odd thing is that it appears to be location specific, as when I check the site from home, still using Safari, I have zero issues. The problem also seems to be machine independent, as I also occasionally get the same javascript errors on my iPad (when at work on the same network).

I'm 100% sure it isn't a syntax error or anything with the javascript, as the file that fails most often is a minified copy of jQuery (downloaded from their site, though hosted on my site's server)

I have tried turning off mod_deflate on the idea that it might be compression that was causing the issue, but this had no effect.

I have spoken to the network admins at both my end, and the hosting server end and they claim that it isn't anything wrong with their network, though they are possibly just deflecting a complex issue.

Any ideas on how I can narrow down the issue?

Comment: Maybe the content-length header that isn't correct? But then agan, then you would think that it was  problem everywhere.

Comment: reminds me a bit of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848505/javascript-game-module-raphael-not-defined.

Comment: @jack Yes that sounds plausible, but it doesn't explain the intermittency. @Hermann I do have a chain of `<script src="">` calls each dependent on the first one loading, but doesn't html retrieve synchronously?

Comment: remember to do </script> as well. That might force the script into loading the next only after the former is finished. If they don't load in the given order you may get trouble. My game there worked for about a year and then stopped working when i moved to another city, turned out the loading sequence changed by being elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: Oh yea I do have the closure tag too.